# How to Update Value in First N Rows by Group in a Multi-Index Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am attempting to update the first N rows in a multi-index dataframe but was having a bit of trouble finding a solution so thought I'd create a post for it.

The example code is as follows:

```
# Imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Set Up Data Frame
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df['DATE'] = dates
df['CATEGORY'] = ['A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B']

# Set Index
df.set_index(['CATEGORY','DATE'],inplace=True)
df.sort(inplace=True)

# Get First Two Rows of Each Category
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0:2])

# Set The Value of Column 'C' Equal to Zero
# ???
```

So I was able to get as far as selecting the rows using "iloc", but after that I'm not sure how to set column "C" equal to zero.  Feels like maybe I'm going about this the wrong way though.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this - first define a function that takes a dataframe, and replaces the first x records with a specified value.

```
def replace_first_x(group_df, x, value):
    group_df.iloc[:x, :] = value
    return group_df
```

Then, pass that into the `groupby` object with apply.

```
In [97]: df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda df: replace_first_x(df, 2, 9999))
Out[97]: 
                               A            B            C            D
CATEGORY DATE                                                          
A        2000-01-01  9999.000000  9999.000000  9999.000000  9999.000000
         2000-01-03  9999.000000  9999.000000  9999.000000  9999.000000
         2000-01-05     1.590503     0.948911    -0.268071     0.622280
         2000-01-07    -0.493866     1.222231     0.125037     0.071064
B        2000-01-02  9999.000000  9999.000000  9999.000000  9999.000000
         2000-01-04  9999.000000  9999.000000  9999.000000  9999.000000
         2000-01-06     1.663430    -1.170716     2.044815    -2.081035
         2000-01-08     1.593104     0.108531    -1.381218    -0.517312
```

Comment: Thanks chrisb/FooBar, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Appreciate the rule of thumb as well FooBar - that's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, whenever you have to *change* values, rather then just pick them, you cannot proceed using a `lambda` function only, since these only allow selection.

A very boiled down way to proceed is

```
def replace_first(group):
    group.iloc[0:2] = 99
    return group
```

and then just do

```
In[144]: df.groupby(level=0).apply(replace_first)
Out[144]: 
                             A          B          C          D
CATEGORY DATE                                                  
A        2000-01-01  99.000000  99.000000  99.000000  99.000000
         2000-01-03  99.000000  99.000000  99.000000  99.000000
         2000-01-05   0.458031   1.959409   0.622295   0.959019
         2000-01-07   0.934521  -2.016685   1.046456   1.489070
B        2000-01-02  99.000000  99.000000  99.000000  99.000000
         2000-01-04  99.000000  99.000000  99.000000  99.000000
         2000-01-06  -0.117322  -1.664436   1.582124   0.486796
         2000-01-08  -0.225379   0.794846  -0.021214  -0.510768
```

Comment: What if you only wanted to change the value of one column?