# Efficiently assign value to first row in groupby

Tags: python, pandas

In my dataframe `df1` I want to assign a new value to `val1` in the *first* row of every group. The new value depends on the group and is stored in `df2`.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'group': list('aaabbb'), 'val1': [2, 3, 6, 3, 7, 10]})
print df1
#  group  val1
#0     a     2
#1     a     3
#2     a     6
#3     b     3
#4     b     7
#5     b    10
​
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['a', 'b'], 'val2': [1, 2]})
print df2
#  group  val2
#0     a     1
#1     b     2

# Desired Output:
#  group  val1
#0     a     1  <- updated
#1     a     3
#2     a     6
#3     b     2  <- updated
#4     b     7
#5     b    10
```

My first solution was merging the two data frames and using a custom function to  assign `val2` to `val1` in the first row as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804832/how-to-update-value-in-first-n-rows-by-group-in-a-multi-index-pandas-dataframe). This works but is very slow and has high memory usage:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='group')

def set_first_value(group):
    group['val1'].iat[0] = group['val2'].iat[0]
    return group

df3.groupby('group').apply(set_first_value)
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='group')
```

Is there a more efficient way of changing the value of the first element in every group?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a better solution while writing this post, which is some 10 times faster. It works using groupby.first()

Here's the benchmark:

```
# setup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
n = 100000
m = 100
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'group': range(n)*m, 'val1': range(n*m)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'group': range(n), 'val2': np.random.randint(1,100, size=n)})
```

*Slower method using customer function:*

```
%%time
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='group')

def set_first_value(group):
    group['val1'].iloc[0] = group['val2'].iloc[0]
    return group

df3.groupby('group').apply(set_first_value)
```

CPU times: user 55.9 s, sys: 2.81 s, total: 58.7 s
Wall time: 59.8 s

***Faster method using groupby.first():***

```
%%time
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='group')
df3['ix'] = df3.index
ix_first = df3.groupby('group').first()['ix']
df3['val1'] = df3['val2'].where(df3['ix'].isin(ix_first), df3['val1'])
```

CPU times: user 3.41 s, sys: 1.2 s, total: 4.62 s
Wall time: 4.78 s