# Computing new column conditional on max of group of other column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a multiindexed dataframe I've recreated a small portion of here.

Each 'Instance' has a different number of IDs.  Each ID has two factors, Factor1 and Factor2.  I'd like two new columns.  The first is simple, it is 100 divided by the number of IDs in the instance (the Count).  This is the 'evenSpread' column.

```
                         Factor1  Factor2  evenSpread    dropONE
Place Instance Count ID                                         
Home  1        7     1        20       18   14.285714  16.666667
                     2        22       19   14.285714  16.666667
                     4        36       40   14.285714  16.666667
                     5        32       30   14.285714  16.666667
                     6         1        7   14.285714  16.666667
                     7        99       90   14.285714  16.666667
                     8         5        9   14.285714  16.666667
      2        8     1        10        8   12.500000  14.285714
                     3        20       19   12.500000  14.285714
                     4        30       35   12.500000  14.285714
                     5        40       55   12.500000  14.285714
                     6        70       50   12.500000  14.285714
                     7        50       60   12.500000  14.285714
                     8        60       52   12.500000  14.285714
                     9        70       88   12.500000  14.285714
```

The second ('dropONE') is more difficult and I'm sure there are a few concepts I'm missing to get this done right.  I want to drop one of the ID with the highest value in Factor1 and populate the column with 100/(count-1) if it's included and 0 if not.  The 2nd part to this is if the max of Factor1 happens TWICE then check Factor2 and drop the smaller of them.

I don't know if this can be done in one assignment without having to create any other columns, but I'm stumped.

The dropONE column should be 16.66667 for all in Instance 1 except 0 for ID 7, where Factor1 is 99.  It should be 14.285714 for all in Instance 2 except 0 for ID 6, where Factor 1 is 70 (the max of F1) and Factor2 is 50 (50 is lower than 88).  This is what I want to see:

```
                         Factor1  Factor2  evenSpread    dropONE
Place Instance Count ID                                         
Home  1        7     1        20       18   14.285714  16.666667
                     2        22       19   14.285714  16.666667
                     4        36       40   14.285714  16.666667
                     5        32       30   14.285714  16.666667
                     6         1        7   14.285714  16.666667
                     7        99       90   14.285714  0
                     8         5        9   14.285714  16.666667
      2        8     1        10        8   12.500000  14.285714
                     3        20       19   12.500000  14.285714
                     4        30       35   12.500000  14.285714
                     5        40       55   12.500000  14.285714
                     6        70       50   12.500000  0
                     7        50       60   12.500000  14.285714
                     8        60       52   12.500000  14.285714
                     9        70       88   12.500000  14.285714
```

I can't even get the first condition to work, let alone the second.  Here's my code so far.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

my_data = {'Place': ['Home', 'Home', 'Home', 'Home', 'Home', 'Home', 'Home',
                     'Home', 'Home', 'Home', 'Home', 'Home', 'Home', 'Home', 'Home'],
           'Instance': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
           'Count': [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
                     8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
           'ID': [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
                  1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
           'Factor1': [20, 22, 36, 32, 1, 99, 5,
                       10, 20, 30, 40, 70, 50, 60, 70],
           'Factor2': [18, 19, 40, 30, 7, 90, 9,
                       8, 19, 35, 55, 50, 60, 52, 88],
           }

df = pd.DataFrame(my_data)
df = df[['Place', 'Instance', 'Count', 'ID', 'Factor1', 'Factor2']]
df.set_index(['Place', 'Instance', 'Count', 'ID'], inplace=True)

print(df)

df['evenSpread'] = 100 / df.index.get_level_values('Count')
df['dropONE'] = 100 / (df.index.get_level_values('Count') - 1)  # WRONG AS WRITTEN
print(df)

# df['dropONE'] = np.where(df['Factor1'] == df.groupby(level=[0, 1, 2])['Factor1'].max(), 0, 1)
print(df)

print(df.groupby(level=[0, 1, 2])['Factor1'].max())
```

The groupby in the np.where isn't working and erroring out, I know it's because I'm comparing different sized objects, but not sure how to do this properly.

Incidentally, that last print out of the groupby shows this:

```
Place  Instance  Count
Home   1         7        99
       2         8        70
Name: Factor1, dtype: int64
```

Thanks much guys.

**EDIT #1**

Not sure if this helps but I sorted each group with the following.  Then maybe there is a way to create a True/False flag column based on the order of each group?   Again, a group would be everything in an Instance.

```
print(df.sort_values(by=['Factor1', 'Factor2'], ascending=[True, False]).sort_index(
    level='Instance', sort_remaining=False))
```

This gives:

```
                         Factor1  Factor2  evenSpread    dropONE
Place Instance Count ID                                         
Home  1        7     6         1        7   14.285714  16.666667
                     8         5        9   14.285714  16.666667
                     1        20       18   14.285714  16.666667
                     2        22       19   14.285714  16.666667
                     5        32       30   14.285714  16.666667
                     4        36       40   14.285714  16.666667
                     7        99       90   14.285714  16.666667
      2        8     1        10        8   12.500000  14.285714
                     3        20       19   12.500000  14.285714
                     4        30       35   12.500000  14.285714
                     5        40       55   12.500000  14.285714
                     7        50       60   12.500000  14.285714
                     8        60       52   12.500000  14.285714
                     6        70       88   12.500000  14.285714
                     9        70       50   12.500000  14.285714
```

Comment: Id say the first condition is working? 100/7 and 100/8 if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Paula, yes 'evenSpread' is working.  It's 'dropONE' ... where there are 2 conditions - Factor 1 max and then min of Factor 2 if there is a tie.  I've tried to make this as clear as I can, sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: When you say "and populate the column with 100/(count-1) if it's included and 0 if not" , what is "it"?

Comment: I want 'dropONE' to be 0 if 'Factor1' is the max of it's group.  In the event of two 'Factor1' maxes (IDs 6 and 9 in Instance 2), I want to drop the one with the lower 'Factor2'.

Answer (score 1):

Hours of searching and trial and error and I've learned a few things.  Sorting was the key.  The following was adapted from [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804832/how-to-update-value-in-first-n-rows-by-group-in-a-multi-index-pandas-dataframe)

```
def replace_first_x(group):
    group.iloc[-1, -1:] = 0
    return group

df = df.groupby(level=[0, 1, 2]).apply(replace_first_x)
print(df)
```

And my output!

```
                         Factor1  Factor2  evenSpread    dropONE
Place Instance Count ID                                         
Home  1        7     6         1        7   14.285714  16.666667
                     8         5        9   14.285714  16.666667
                     1        20       18   14.285714  16.666667
                     2        22       19   14.285714  16.666667
                     5        32       30   14.285714  16.666667
                     4        36       40   14.285714  16.666667
                     7        99       90   14.285714   0.000000
      2        8     1        10        8   12.500000  14.285714
                     3        20       19   12.500000  14.285714
                     4        30       35   12.500000  14.285714
                     5        40       55   12.500000  14.285714
                     7        50       60   12.500000  14.285714
                     8        60       52   12.500000  14.285714
                     9        70       88   12.500000  14.285714
                     6        70       50   12.500000   0.000000
```

I am curious if there are any built in functions or better ways to do this though.  This works, but is a little slow (df over 500k rows).